# Replace multiple blank spaces in string in Google Data Studio (Regex)

Tags: regex, whitespace, looker-studio, regexp-replace, re2

I'm trying to clean up my data for a Google Data Studio report by replacing multiple spaces in a string with a single space using a `REGEXP_REPLACE` formula, but I cannot work out how to do it. I think this is a peculiarity when working in Google Data Studio.

Here is an example...

Record with Campaign name=

```
"   This       is  an     example     string  with many  blank     spaces     "
```

I then create a Custom field in Data Studio with formula

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign name,'/s','')
```

I have tried adding in multiple combinations of:

`/s+`
`/s*`
`\/s*\`
`s/g`
`[/s]`
`/s{5}`

Note: do not be confused...when looking at the output results in Data Studio, Google strips out the extra spaces for *presentation purposes* - but they are still there and mess up sorting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of the [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below, which incorporate the [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583446) function to ensure that any potential trailing spaces are removed; the first [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) Calculated Field uses a [Raw Literal](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10495775) (indicated by the `R` before the RegEx section), requiring a single `\` while the second Calculated Field without the Raw Literal requires `\\` for special RegEx characters and as the escape sequence:

### 1) RegEx WITH Raw Literal

```
TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign name, R"\s+", " "))
```

### 2) RegEx WITHOUT Raw Literal

```
TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign name, "\\s+", " "))
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f99b9f4a-8eb2-4065-b4e1-868f8338e42a) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VMtq2DX-Ndkpz8wNOzFVuY4gAQu8Zq3xxqXu75gpje8/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]